# php_monetdb.dll

Tags: php, windows, build, monetdb

I need the php_monetdb.dll for php 5.4. I've found that by building the monetDB with the HAVE_PHP=1 option on windows will create the dll, but the build procedure fails at numerous points. I am using the monetdb source from sourceforge which is a little outdated one. The newer version has problems in the .msc files itself so proceeding to the build itself is a pain. The older version that I am trying on is atleast passing the nmake step but failing on the nmake install step. The reasons vary from component to component. One states that the devenv  /build does not exist. For this I copied the vcexpress and renamed it to devenv. I am not sure if this is right but when I run it from the command prompt it seems to work ok with a few warning alerts shown. During other make installs, the header files seem to be missing. Could anyone please help me with this. Also please let me know if there is any other alternative for this approach of getting php_monetdb.dll.

P.S: I am using windows 7, MSVC 10 express, PHP 5.4.4

Answer (score 1):

For the build questions, see http://bugs.monetdb.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3121

For php_monetdb.dll, see
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20120717145132.GU49719%40cwi.nl&forum_name=monetdb-developers
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=500581D5.8030808%40acm.org&forum_name=monetdb-developers